# Wordpress Migration PHP Issues with Visual Composer Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

The Website is Currently Running Wordpress
The Theme is Polytechnic Version: 1.1.7

This site is using WPBakery Visual Composer 4.7.4

Everything displays correctly, but when the Editor is opened the **Visual Composer** loads endlessly.

When opened the WP Debug Log returns:

```
Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /wp-content/themes/polytechnic/mythology-core/option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 326

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /polytechnic/mythology-core/option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 326

Warning: trigger_error() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 4777

Warning: trigger_error() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 4777

Warning: trigger_error() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 4777
```

Line 4777:

```php
wp_get_current_user()
```

```
Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /polytechnic/mythology-core/option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 98

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /themes/polytechnic/mythology-core/option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 326
```

Line 326:

```php
$path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
```

Line 93-101:

```php
    $path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_stylesheet(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
          define( 'OT_LANG_DIR', trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . $path ) . trailingslashit( 'languages' ) . 'theme-mode' );
          
        } else {
        
          $path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
          define( 'OT_LANG_DIR', trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . $path ) . trailingslashit( 'languages' ) . 'theme-mode' );
          
        }
```

---

```
Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 844
            
   Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 844
        
   Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 844
```

I traced the Warning on class-vc-frontend-editor.php back to:

```php
if ( WPBMap::getParam( $s, 'content' ) !== false ) {
    $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $content;
}
```

I am just trying to get Visual Composer running correctly first.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Visual Composer plugin usually comes with the theme and doesn't get updated automatically. Is it up-to-date? Are you using the php version that is compatible with your VC version?

Comment: @ozgur It seems that Plesk doesn't support PHP 5 so I dont even know where to go from there. Ive tried replacing the plugin with the new Visual Composer plugin but then the shortcodes just appear as text.

Comment: Hey, it's not good to show/share the full path of your application in the error messages, you may expose some sensitives information of your client. And there is no need to share the domain name of your application, you may expose potential issues in your app which may lead to something bad. Don't do that please!

Comment: @TylerKanz PHP 5 is not support on most hosting companies any more as it is pretty old and unsecure. You should be using at least PHP 7.2 if possible

Comment: @MAZux Good call. Made some edits to the post.

Comment: What have you changed in the meantime?

Comment: @ozgur Im found a slightly different version of JS Composer. I installed it on the original server and am going to try and migrate over to the new server. It seems that both servers are using PHP 7.3 so hopefully this will be a solution.

Comment: This is why I'm loathe to use these third party builders - they sell themselves and ship as these great solutions and then the dev team makes some changes and you either get a site that's broken like yours, or you update to their newest version and have to re-do a bunch of work.  They also tend to have negative impacts on performance in the back end.

Comment: Update to JS Composer slightly helped but still broken. I am now able to open the Editor but nothing is saving/being called and I am getting the current errors.

Comment: "Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 844" I believe this is where a lot of its coming from.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I know. I have ran into this countless times while migrating 60+ WordPress sites to a new webserver. Its been a huge pain.

Comment: Fixed. Was able to update to the 6.4.0 Version of WP Bakery Page builder with PHP 7.2. This version reads the VC shortcode and doesn't have the deprecations.